# Scope javascripts to be outside admin

Tags: javascript, 8

Now when we are almost there using purely YML files to include JavaScript, is it possible to include javascripts everywhere except for in the Drupal administration? Beta 4 does not allow the #attached property anymore, so this solution would be best suited in a YML setup.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Sure. Drupal 8 still allows #attached, the difference is just that you specify a library instead of a specific javascript file, but that is irrelevant for your question.

You can implement hook_page_attachments() and ask the route context if this is an admin route.

```
/**
 * Implements hook_page_attachments().
 */
function yourmodule_page_attachments(&$page) {
  // This returns TRUE for admin paths.
  if (!\Drupal::service('router.admin_context')->isAdminRoute()) {
    $page['#attached']['library'][] = 'yourmodule/yourlibrary';
  }
}
```

Comment: Did the trick, cheers!